# Exiting foreach loop from nested if using exit() stops script totally

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I am building a wordpress plugin for learning reasons and this is the code in question:

```
// display latest facebook posts
// Init a cURL resource
$ch = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=133869316660964");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
// Make facebook think it is being accessed by a browser to avoid compatability issues
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$data = curl_exec( $ch );

// instanciate a new xml element
$fb = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$i = 0; // set the counter for the foreach loop to 0

echo "<ul>"; // begin the UL

foreach ($fb->channel->item as $item) {
    // foreach item within the tree perform this loop twice
    $link = $item->link; // set the link address
    $post = $item->description; // set the post data
    echo "<li>" . $post, ' :::::: ', '<a href="' . 
    $link . '">' . $link, PHP_EOL . "</a></li>";
    $i++;
    if($i == 2){
        exit();
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

However when I inspect the HTML I see this: (quick snippet from the very bottom)

```
846656&id=133869316660964
</a></li>
```

This is the last part of the foreach loop where $i =< 2 so using exit appears to be stopping the script totally, am I correct in saying that or is there another error causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit();` stops php execution. Try using `break;` to exit the loop

[PHP break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed :) will mark as correct when it lets me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

use **break** and not **exit**

Exit terminates the whole execution of php script